# Django Admin Save and add another preselected fields

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django 1.5 app, and am having to do my own data entry :P.  I've noticed that the "Save and add another" button is slightly misleading, as it does not hold the context of the previous selections.  Say for example, that my model has a ForeignKey relation to another model (resulting in a dropdown select).  Is there a way (that I'm not seeing) to have it preselect that dropdown based on the previous selection (when using save and add another)?

Comment: I don't think there's anything built in, but you could do it with some Javascript (or, more complicatedly, custom admin views) and a custom `response_add` method on the admin class to put the selected values or a PK into the querystring.

Comment: Interesting.  Ok, I'll give that a whirl and report back how it turns out.  This question was in an effort to minimize my data entry...  sigh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the `ModelAdmin.save_as` option:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    save_as = True
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_as

Comment: Oh my gosh.  Go figure, read the docs...  Thank you for the link, while not exactly what I was thinking, completely solves my issue.  Now to facepalm myself for not reading the docs close enough...